# Find out if a specific column in Excel is "part" of a colmn grouping

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to check if a column is part of a (colapsed) group? I was under the impression that you can achieve it with the [`range.ShowDetail`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.ShowDetail) attribute, so:

```
SomeWorksheet.Columns(SomeColumn).EntireColumn.ShowDetail
```

would returns `False` only if that column is part of a collapsed group.

I tried it out, put in my case it always returns true regardless if the column is hidden and/or in a (collapsed/uncollapsed) group. What am I missing?

Comment: try `.Hidden` instead of `.ShowDetail`

Comment: You can test if a column is part of a group (not whether it's collapsed) by checking its [`OutlineLevel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.outlinelevel).

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks, unfortunatly `SomeColumn.Hidden` would also give me a `True` if the column is "just" hidden but not part of a group (which can be the case in my table).

Comment: @BigBen I will try that, thanks. What exactly it `.ShowDetail` suppose to do, if it does not do the things I describe in my question?

Comment: It may be buggy, I'm not sure to be honest.